# How to get required output in JSOn format using ADF derived column

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I need an output like this

[image]

I have the required columns(Article Code,PromotionPrice,SalesPrice) coming from CosmosDB, rest all are hardcoded.

I have done the below changes in ADF derived column.

```
[@(
            articleCode=id,
            ColorOverrule=toString(null()),
            DescriptionOverrule=toString(null()),
            promotionPrice=Price_For,
            salePrice=Price_From)
]
```

[image]

But with this I am getting output like below, Which is not correct.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried earlier in same scenario, Use collect() function instead of manually adding [] symbols inside derived columns, using expression with [] symbols will not help to yield array. Add another Derived column and use collect function.

Comment: This is correct, just use Aggregate transformation. You need to use collect() to create an array of Materials. Create the Materials structure, then add an Aggregate transformation without any grouping. For the aggregate expression, use collect(Materials).